# Avoiding having static const variables everywhere

Tags: c++, static, constants

I have the below code in a C wrapper to a C++ class. I need to return the string value of the response from my json::value object. The problem is, using c_str() returns a pointer that is destroyed at the end of the function. Thus I have the below horrendous and unsafe code:-

```
const char* const response_Json(CResponse *resp) {
    using namespace myclient;
    Response *t = (Response*)resp;
    const web::json::value& json = t->Json(); // NOTE: Json() can ONLY be called ONCE
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << json; // REQUIRED to get raw JSON as text, as serialize(void) does NOT work
    //t->Json().serialize(stream); // Doesn't work - blank result
    std::string asstr = stream.str();
    static const std::string& statref = stream.str(); // REQUIRED to ensure reference to string, and thus contained c_str, is not destroyed
    static const char* pref = statref.c_str(); // REQUIRED so we have a local char pointer that is not temporary, and thus destroyed at function's exit

    return pref;
}
```

I've found that both statref and pref are required to be declared as static const in order for a value to actually be returned rather than a hanging pointer (I.e. static const's required up the whole object graph to asstr) but I'm not sure why. I would have thought the one for pref would have sufficed.

I'd like to remove all static variables as this function will be called multiple times, and perhaps in parallel.

What I need to do is return the C char*, or a copy thereof, that avoids the use of static const. I've been searching for days and can't find the answer anywhere.

The conclusion I've come to is that I need to pass in a char* that this function modifies, rather than returns.

Comment: You need to pass a buffer to the `response_Json` function and that function should copy the string into the buffer.

Comment: Returning `stddup(stream.str().c_str())` might be a solution, User is required to free it afterward.

Comment: This doesn't work anyway. `static`s (like all other objects) are only initialised _once_. You'd have to perform an assignment later for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a buffer to the `response_Json` function and that function should copy the string into the buffer the caller provides.

Basially you need this:

```
void const response_Json(CResponse *resp, char *buffer) {
    using namespace myclient;
    Response *t = (Response*)resp;
    const web::json::value& json = t->Json(); // NOTE: Json() can ONLY be called ONCE
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << json; // REQUIRED to get raw JSON as text, as serialize(void) does NOT work
    //t->Json().serialize(stream); // Doesn't work - blank result
    std::string asstr = stream.str();
    strcpy(buffer, asstr.c_str);
}
```

For the sake of simplicity no buffer overrun checking is done here.

Maybe there is still room for improvement in the json stuff section of the function.